# Problemas tabs responsive

Tags: php, adminlte

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web basada en Adminlte, el caso es que en el ficha de los clientes quiero poner varias pestañas para poder ver diferentes apartados (Datos generales, visitas, pedidos, etc)

Este es el código que tengo para las pestañas:

```
<div class="content">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
  <button class="nav-link active" id="perfil-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#perfil" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="perfil" aria-selected="true"><a class="btn btn-app"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>General</a></button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
  <button class="nav-link" id="clientes-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#clientes" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="clientes" aria-selected="false"><a class="btn btn-app"><i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i>Propuestas</a></button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
  <button class="nav-link" id="visitas-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#visitas" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="visitas" aria-selected="false"><a class="btn btn-app"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Visitas</a></button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="perfil" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="perfil-tab">
    
    <?php
      include("socios_perfil_edit.php");
     
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="clientes" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="clientes-tab" >

    <?php
        include("propuestas.php");
      ?>
  </div>
 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="visitas" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="visitas-tab" >
    
    <?php
        include("visitas-socio.php");
      ?>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

El problema es que en el include `propuestas.php` tengo un datables y sólo se muestra correctamente responsive y muestra el botón control si en su tab correspondiente indicó `"show active"` y el problema es que no quiero que se muestre esa pestaña cuando entras en la ficha, quiero que se muestre la primera, pero si pongo el `"show active"` sólo en la primera, la segunda pestaña no funciona correctamente.

Comment: despues de un tiempo con otras cosas he vuelto con este tema. Alguien puede echarme una mano, estoy un poco desesperado